# Unable to disable EditText programmatically in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to disable an `EditText` programmatically in `Kotlin` but I am not finding any method to do. I tried below code which didnt work:

```
panEditText.focusable = false //Requires API 26 and above.

panEditText.enabled = false //No such method found
```

How to disable `EditText` in `Kotlin` programming language?

Comment: By disable do you want deny userInput or just hide it from the view? If you want to hide it will be panEditText.visibility=view.INVISIBLE

Comment: disable user from entering values @udit7395

Comment: setEnabled is indeed inaccessible from kotlin, can't figure out why though

Comment: use isEnabled instead of enabled.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use **`isEnabled`**.

> Set the enabled state of this view.

```
 panEditText.isEnabled =false
```

**Method Overview**

```
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled == isEnabled()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!enabled) {
            // Hide the soft input if the currently active TextView is disabled
            InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
            if (imm != null && imm.isActive(this)) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        super.setEnabled(enabled);

        if (enabled) {
            // Make sure IME is updated with current editor info.
            InputMethodManager imm = InputMethodManager.peekInstance();
            if (imm != null) imm.restartInput(this);
        }

        // Will change text color
        if (mEditor != null) {
            mEditor.invalidateTextDisplayList();
            mEditor.prepareCursorControllers();

            // start or stop the cursor blinking as appropriate
            mEditor.makeBlink();
        }
    }
```